# d3.js lollipop chart - animated

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

I am working on a d3 application - which features a bar chart with nodules on the top. I am keen to get this animated - so the bars grow to the point of rest and the nodules sprout like flowers.

So the nodules are either developed at the start and the bars just rise -- or the bars rise up and then the nodules flower.

//old js fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/s1f4hzpu/1/

//current animation attempts
http://jsfiddle.net/9yvn8c4q/

```js
var $this = $('.lollipopchart');

var data = [{
    label: 'Toblerone',
    value: 10,
  },
  {
    label: 'Snickers',
    value: 25,
  },
  {
    label: 'Jawbreakers',
    value: 60,
  },
  {
    label: 'Gummi Worms',
    value: 20,
  },
];

var width = $this.data('width'),
  height = $this.data('height');

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#eb6383", "#fa9191", "#ffe9c5", "#b4f2e1"]);

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.total = +d.value;
});

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 85,
    left: 20
  },
  width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .padding(0.9);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0]);

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.label;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.total;
})]);

var svg = d3.select($this[0])
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'lollipopchart')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var lollipop = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'lollipop');

var bars = lollipop
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'bars')

bars.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.label);
  })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.total);
  });



var lolliradian = 10;

var circles = lollipop
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'circles');

circles.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  //.transition()
  //.duration(1000)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return (x(d.label) + x.bandwidth() / 2);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("r", lolliradian)
  .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })


var innercircles = lollipop
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'innercircles');

innercircles.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  //.transition()
  //.duration(1000)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return (x(d.label) + x.bandwidth() / 2);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("r", lolliradian - 5)
  .attr('fill', '#ffffff')



lollipop.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", ".15em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");

lollipop.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

```css
body {
  background: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<h1>LolliPop I</h1>
<div class="lollipopchart" data-width="300" data-height="300" />
```

Comment: Your code seems to be an exact copy from [this site](https://www.nuomiphp.com/eplan/328976.html), even including the commented out `//.transition()` code. What have you tried so far? Show us that you've invested as much time in this as you're asking us to

Comment: that is my old code -  that transition code was for appending circles - but no stepped animation trends

Comment: that was as far as I got - building the chart - but with no animations - here is the old jsfiddle  - http://jsfiddle.net/s1f4hzpu/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9yvn8c4q/  -- the bars now animate - but the wrong way - from top to bottom

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/by9cv5s3/ -- latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need jQuery, you can do everything you want with regular d3.
Regardless, if you want to make the bars grow, you need to know that `y=0` is the top and `y=height` is the bottom, so you need to actually *decrease* `y` as you increase `height`.

I also wouldn't draw a circle in front of another circle, but would use `stroke` and `fill` colours instead. If you make a stroke of 5 pixels wide, then it looks the same as in your example.

```js
var data = [{
    label: 'Toblerone',
    value: 10,
  },
  {
    label: 'Snickers',
    value: 25,
  },
  {
    label: 'Jawbreakers',
    value: 60,
  },
  {
    label: 'Gummi Worms',
    value: 20,
  },
];

var width = +d3.select(".lollipopchart").attr('data-width'),
  height = +d3.select(".lollipopchart").attr('data-height');

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#eb6383", "#fa9191", "#ffe9c5", "#b4f2e1"]);

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.total = +d.value;
});

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 85,
    left: 20
  },
  width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .padding(0.9);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0]);

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.label;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.total;
})]);

var svg = d3.select('.lollipopchart')
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'lollipopchart')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var lollipop = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'lollipop');

var bars = lollipop
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'bars')

bars.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.label);
  })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .attr("y", height)
  .transition()
  .duration(1500)
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.total);
  });

var lolliradian = 10;

var circles = lollipop
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'circles');

circles.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return (x(d.label) + x.bandwidth() / 2);
  })
  .attr("cy", height)
  .attr("r", x.bandwidth() / 2)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .attr("stroke-width", 5)
  .attr('stroke', function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .transition()
  .duration(1500)
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .on("end", function() {
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(500)
      .attr("r", lolliradian);
  });


lollipop.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", ".15em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");

lollipop.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

```css
body {
  background: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<h1>LolliPop I</h1>
<div class="lollipopchart" data-width="300" data-height="300" />
```